# Laravel 5.3 Advance Search Query

Tags: laravel, select, where-clause

In my Laravel 5.3 project, I have a form with one textbox (keywords), and two select dropdowns (category, and location). I am trying to build the select clause in my controller but it is not working when I put where for either table_1.category or table_1.location.

```
    $keys       = \Request::get('keyword');
    $category   = \Request::get('category');
    $location   = \Request::get('location');

    $myrecord = mytable_1::join('table_2', 'table_2.user_id', '=', 'table_1.user_id')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $keys = \Request::get('keyword');
            $query->where('table_1.title', 'like','%'.$keys.'%')
                  ->orWhere('table_2.company', 'like','%'.$keys.'%');
        })
        ->where('table_1.category', $category)
        ->where('table_1.location', $location)
        ->select('table_2.*', 'table_1.*')
        ->paginate(30);
```

Please advise the way to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

U need to use 'use()' method to pass a parameter into your where query...if your parameter contains array then you can use a foreach loop. I think it will work...

```
    $keys  = \Request::get('keyword');
    $category   = \Request::get('category');
    $location   = \Request::get('location');

    $myrecord = mytable_1::join('table_2', 'table_2.user_id', '=','table_1.user_id')
    ->where(function($query) use ($keys){
        $query->where('table_1.title', 'like','%'.$keys.'%')
        ->orWhere('table_2.company', 'like','%'.$keys.'%');
    })

    ->where('table_1.category', $category)
    ->where('table_1.location', $location)
    ->select('table_2.*', 'table_1.*')
    ->paginate(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel conventions then I would expect that the column names would be `table_1.category_id` and `table_1.location_id`. If `$category` and `$location` are the integer IDs of those record then it should work the way you expect.

Comment: Yes, I use 'table_1.category' instead of 'table_1.category_id', and 'table_1.location' instead of 'table_1.location_id' but is it wrong if I put these as varchar?

Comment: They should probably be integers, I'm not sure if they would work as expected if they are a different format. It would probably depend on the database engine. Perhaps you might be better constructing the raw SQL first and then working it back into Eloquent once you know it works.

Comment: Thank you for all comments. I fixed it by using condition.